# Create contract that receives and sends bonus money to many addresses. What is the gas price?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, gas

I would like to create a contract that holds references to 20 Ethereum addresses. Each address has some associated Ethereum value. I want to send the message to this contract later and call function "payBonus" which accepts the ordered array of addresses.

1st address in array gets 60% of total sum of Ethereum, 2nd - 30%, third - 10%. All other 17 addresses get nothing.

Imagine 20 people made bets and I decide who are the winners.

I have few questions

1. It's really expensive to store data. Do I have to store 20 bytes (people who bet) * 20 addresses + byte_size_of_ethereum_type * 20?
2. Do I have to pay for 20*3 bytes while sending the message to my contract "payBonus" function?

Thanks!

> It's not clear why the other 17 addresses need to be stored?

The scenario is:
I create betting contract. 20 people take part in it and deposit money to the contract. The idea is to record which user has put money on the contract.

> If the contract already has the 3 address, you don't need to pay for the 20*3 bytes when calling payBonus

Contract knows who and how much deposited funds to it. The contract doesn't know who won. Contract owner (me) should send three top winner addresses. I should send a message to a contract with three addresses and it should cost a gas since message changes state of contract and transferred over

> Ethereum
>   Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange! It's not clear why the other 17 addresses need to be stored?  Q1: Since each word in Solidity is 32 bytes, usually Solidity will use one word per address.  Q2: If the contract already has the 3 address, you don't need to pay for the 20*3 bytes when calling payBonus.  Also, the spelling is Ethereum :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've added details to my post